# How do I extract the hours and minutes of two time picker dialogs in the same onTimeSet()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, timepicker

I have already implemented time pickers on button press which are in a fragment (`Work`) but how can i extract the the hour and the minutes of both dialogs to separate variables using only one onTimeSet(), which is located in the `MainActivity`?

This is my `onTimeSet()` in my `MainActivity`:

```
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textstart);
        textView.setText("Hour: "+ i + " Minutes: "+ i1);

        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

    }
```

And this is my `Work` fragment:

```
Button timeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.timeButton);
        timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePicker_Fragment();
                timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
            }
        });

        Button timeButton2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.timeButton2);
        timeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker2 = new TimePicker_Fragment();
                timePicker2.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker 2");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the architecture of your application:

Since the `TimePickerFragment` is the only one which can make sense of the `TimePicker` parameter in `onTimeSet()`, it is the logical choice for implementing the `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`.

The two instances of `TimePicker_Fragment` could report back to the hosting `WorkFragment` (and eventually the `Activity`) via some custom interface(s). Use some unique value (a `String` or an enum) to identify them in your custom version of `onTimeSet()`.

For example your Activity could implement a method as follows:

```
@Override
void onCustomTimeSet(String timePickerId, int hour, int minutes){
    switch(timePickerId){
        case "TIME_PICKER":
            // code for time  picker 1 here
            break;
        case "TIME_PICKER_2":
            // code for time  picker 1 here
            break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

...which would be called by the implementation of the "normal" `onTimeSet(TimePicker, int, int)` in `TimePicker_Fragment`

```
@Override
void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i2){
    ((CustomTimePickerListener)getActivity()).onCustomTimeSet("TIME_PICKER_1", i, i2)
}
```

---

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that a `TimePicker` is a `View`, and `View`s can have a *tag* (which can be any type of `Object`, see [View.setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag(java.lang.Object)) ).

So you can have `TimePicker_Fragment` set a *tag* to the `TimePicker`.

Since the `TimePicker` is part of the `TimePickerDialog`, the easiest way to set the *tag* seems to be to have (again) `TimePicker_Fragment` implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`. But this time, the `Activity` could implement the same interface:

Code in `TimePicker_Fragment`

```
void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i2){
    timePicker.setTag("TIME_PICKER");
    ((TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getActivity()).onTimeSet(timePicker, i, i2);
}
```

Code in the `Activity`

```
void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i2){
    String tag = (String)timePicker.getTag();
    switch(tag){
        case "TIME_PICKER":
            // code for time  picker 1 here
            break;
        case "TIME_PICKER_2":
            // code for time  picker 2 here
            break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Code implementing the second solution for the three relevant components:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new Work()).commit();
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1){
        String tag = (String)timePicker.getTag();
        switch(tag){
            case TIME_PICKER:
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textstart);
                textView.setText("Start Hour: "+ i + " Minutes: "+ i1);
                break;
            case TIME_PICKER_2:
                TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textend);
                textView2.setText("Start Hour: "+ i + " Minutes: "+ i1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Work.java

```
public class Work extends Fragment {

    public static final String TIME_PICKER = "TIME_PICKER";
    public static final String TIME_PICKER_2 = "TIME_PICKER_2";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_work, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Work");

        Button timeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = TimePicker_Fragment.instance(TIME_PICKER);
                timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
            }
        });

        Button timeButton2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        timeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker2 =TimePicker_Fragment.instance(TIME_PICKER_2);
                timePicker2.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker 2");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

TimePicker_Fragment.java

```
public class TimePicker_Fragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private static final String KEY_TIMEPICKER_TAG = "KEY_TIMEPICKER_TAG";

    /**
     *
     * @param timePickerTag the tag by which you can identify a TimePicker.  
     *             Will be set as tag to the TimePicker View in onTimeSet()
     * @return x
     */
    public static TimePicker_Fragment instance(String timePickerTag){
        TimePicker_Fragment fragment = new TimePicker_Fragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(KEY_TIMEPICKER_TAG, timePickerTag);
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Context ctx = getContext();
        return new TimePickerDialog(ctx, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ctx));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i2){
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        assert b != null;
        timePicker.setTag(b.getString(KEY_TIMEPICKER_TAG));
        ((TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getActivity()).onTimeSet(timePicker, i, i2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

Have you tried something like that (not sure about the exact syntax) :

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textstart);
    textView.setText("Hour: "+ timePicker.getHour() + " Minutes: "+ timePicker.getMinute());
}
```

You can also add a Listener to your `TimePicker_Fragment` constructor to get the new hour and minute when it's updated.